# Changing colors of selectors in VSCode for Material Theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to have the css selectors to have colors corresponding to the colors in the html theme. Currently elements and classes all share the same orange-y color in the css theme, where I would like their colors to be the same as in the html file. I've looked up how to override colors, but I'm very new to this and couldn't figure out how to change the color for the css files specifically.

Comment: You haven't provided much to go on. If you want a quality answer, it may benefit you to post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your vscode settings.json. Add these configs and modify them as you like.

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "name": "Italicsify for Operator Mono",
            "scope": [
                "modifier",
                "this",
                "comment",
                "storage.modifier",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.js",
                "storage.modifier.js",
                "storage.modifier.ts",
                "storage.modifier.tsx",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.js",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.ts",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.tsx",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.html"
            ],
            "settings": {
                // HTML Attributes styles
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                "foreground": "#89ddff"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[CSS] - ID Selector",
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.id.css",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ],
    // Change theme name to your selected one
    "[Community Material Theme]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - Entity",
                "scope": ["source.css entity", "source.stylus entity"],
                "settings": {
                    // Your desired CSS Selector Style
                    "foreground": "#ffc600",
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - ID Selector",
                "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.id.css",
                "settings": {
                    // Your desired ID Selector Style
                    "foreground": "#ffc600",
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```